# Why does Java StringBuilder use 2147483639 as safe bound?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

**Java version**: openjdk 11.0.19

When I was looking at the source code of `StringBuilder`, I noticed that it checks if the capacity exceeds **`2147483639`** when you use the **`append`** method.

I'm curious why this particular value is used and if there's any specific reason behind it.

**Souce Code**:

```
private int newCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    int oldCapacity = this.value.length >> this.coder;
    int newCapacity = (oldCapacity << 1) + 2;
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0) {
       newCapacity = minCapacity;
    }

    int SAFE_BOUND = 2147483639 >> this.coder;
    return newCapacity > 0 && SAFE_BOUND - newCapacity >= 0 ? newCapacity : this.hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

Comment: It's *very* close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I would assume it's to prevent trying to exceed that limit internally. It's a very large `String`. `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8 == 2147483639`

Comment: I can't find that method in the [openjdk 11.0.19 StringBuilder source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u-dev/blob/jdk-11.0.19-ga/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringBuilder.java).

Comment: Ah. It's in AbstractStringBuilder.

Comment: Where did you find this code, anyway? It looks kind of like it might be decompiler output, not actual source code.

Comment: @TdOnline please [edit] your post to mention (and link to) where you found this code, because the code you're showing [does not appear to exist](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aopenjdk+SAFE_BOUND+%3D+2147483639&type=code) in the openjdk11 code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what that code looks like in the [version](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u-dev/blob/jdk-11.0.19-ga/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#L177) of the openjdk 11.0.19 source code I found when I looked for it:

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate (unless necessary).
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

/**
 * Returns a capacity at least as large as the given minimum capacity.
 * Returns the current capacity increased by the same amount + 2 if
 * that suffices.
 * Will not return a capacity greater than
 * {@code (MAX_ARRAY_SIZE >> coder)} unless the given minimum capacity
 * is greater than that.
 *
 * @param  minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
 * @throws OutOfMemoryError if minCapacity is less than zero or
 *         greater than (Integer.MAX_VALUE >> coder)
 */
private int newCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = value.length >> coder;
    int newCapacity = (oldCapacity << 1) + 2;
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0) {
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    }
    int SAFE_BOUND = MAX_ARRAY_SIZE >> coder;
    return (newCapacity <= 0 || SAFE_BOUND - newCapacity < 0)
        ? hugeCapacity(minCapacity)
        : newCapacity;
}
```

As you can see from the helpful code comments, the value of 2147483639, equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8, was picked because larger allocations might fail on some VMs, due to reserved header space.

I don't know why the code you found looks different.

Comment: Thx！It's because I was looking at the class code, and the explanation in the source code is indeed more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `2 ** 31` is `2147483648`, that's the max range for signed int.

There's probably a few additional bytes used for other book keeping overhead (e.g. tracking string length and maybe null terminator) which leads to the number 2147483639.